# CakePHP search in two fields

Tags: php, cakephp

i have a search input to search on the titles field and i want to search through the `title` and `description` fields with the same input, it's posible?

This is my search funtion:

```
$query = $this->request->query['search'];
$category_id = $this->request->query['category_id'];
$multimedia_type_id = $this->request->query['multimedia_type_id'];

$conditions = array(

  'conditions' => array(            
   'and' => array()));

  if ($query) $conditions['conditions']['and']['Multimedia.title LIKE' ] = "%$query%";
        if ($category_id) $conditions['conditions']['and']['Multimedia.category_id'] = $category_id ;
        if ($multimedia_type_id) $conditions['conditions']['and']['Multimedia.multimedia_type_id'] = $multimedia_type_id ;
```

I want to search on `titles` and `description` at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wanted to say is that you need to search either with the description or with the title. That's an `OR` not an `and`. And then combine this `OR` with an extra `and`.

So check this:

```
$conditions = array(
   'AND' => array(
       'OR' => array(
           'Multimedia.title LIKE' => "%$query%",
           'Multimedia.description LIKE' => "%$query%",
        ),
        'AND' => array(
           'Multimedia.multimedia_type_id' => $multimedia_type_id
           'Multimedia.category_id' => $category_id
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: i have to put this: 'Multimedia.title', 'Multimedia.description' inside the array() ?

Comment: You shouldn't need the extra `AND` index as this should be implied, but it does make it more readable.